# How to make the dot/circle in front of the rectangle?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, frontend

I am trying to build a simple page where I was wondering how do I make the circle with the paragraph comes on top of the rectangle so that the rectangle and the text will appear in the front(on the top)? thank you so much for your help,

```css
  .dot {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -5rem;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 850px;
  background-color: #555;
}

.rectangle-vertical-1 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6%;
}

.rectangle-vertical-2 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #a3a3a3;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6%;
}

.rectangle-vertical-3 {
  height: 180px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #4d4c4c;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6%;
}

.rectangle-vertical-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -9rem;
  "}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <div class="dot">
        <h4>Melrose</h4>
        <p>abc</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
          <div class="rectangle">
            <img class="img" src="https://pic4.zhimg.com/v2-34c6587aa75dd33470cf5f4dddcb6923_1200x500.jpg" alt=""> </div>
          <div class="rectangle-vertical-container">
            <span class="rectangle-vertical-1"></span>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create an example of what you tried so far?  Without your CSS, it's hard to see what we're working with.

Comment: @thingEvery yes, I've added the css, just wondering how do i add snippet?

Comment: "Stack Snippets" are very useful for making questions easier to answer https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @alie, Do you mean like this?? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/abOqaEp

Comment: @ManirajMurugan hi the snippet you sent doesn't look quite right, I just the circle to on top pf the rectangle

Comment: @alie, Top of rectangle mean, the dot should touch the rectangle or not?? Whether like this?? https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/QWbQVYW .. Can you provide your expected result screenshot if possible??

Comment: @alie you can try adding `position: relative` to `.dot`

Comment: @Zuber yes, that workds!! thank you